# Python list comprehension in Go

Tags: python, go

I'm translating below Python function to Go. It's using list comprehension which I don't think is available in Go. What's the best way to translate it to Go ?

```
def list1s():
        return ["10." + str(x) + "." + str(y) + ".1" for x in range(192, 256) for y in range(0, 256)]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use explicit for loops. However, you should not try to simply translate what you do in a language into another.

```
func list1s() []string {
    res := make([]string, 0, 256*64)
    for x := 192; x < 256; x++ {
        for y := 0; y < 256; y++ {
            res = append(res, fmt.Sprintf("10.%d.%d.1", x, y))
        }
    }
    return res
}
```

Comment: I suppose your recommendation to avoid simple translations between languages means that this code is not idiomatic in go, is it? Honest curiosity, I know nothing about go.

Comment: @Paulo Scardine It is. But when writing in a language, you have to think about how to solve the problem for this language, not in another and translate after.